# How do I make a list of list objects In VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, list, controls

Hi I know this may sound a little weird but I am trying to have a master list that contains other lists of controls. Here is what I have so far.

```
'Create master list of control lists. Each member of this list will be a list containing one rows worth of controls

Dim masterList As New List(Of List(Of Control))
Dim rowList As New List(Of Control)

For Each Control As Control In flpExceptionControls.Controls

    rowList.Add(Control)

    If flpExceptionControls.GetFlowBreak(Control) = True Then
        masterList.Add(rowList)
        rowList.Clear()
    End If

Next

For Each row As List(Of Control) In masterList

    MsgBox(row.Count.ToString)

Next
```

The message box is showing that each of those lists have a count of 0, but I know it is adding all the controls to those objects because it shows it when I step through the code. I'm guessing I am just not accessing the list objects contained in the master list correctly.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
If flpExceptionControls.GetFlowBreak(Control) = True Then
   masterList.Add(rowList)
   rowList.Clear()
End If
```

You are clearing the contents of the *same list*, which you are then adding some new items to, and clearing again, and adding the *same reference* to the master list. Essentially; all of your items in masterList are the same, empty list.

You need to create a new sub-list for each. Don't clear any lists.

```
Dim rowList As New List(Of Control)
For Each Control As Control In flpExceptionControls.Controls
    rowList.Add(Control)
    If flpExceptionControls.GetFlowBreak(Control) = True Then
        masterList.Add(rowList)
        rowList = New List(Of Control)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Yeah that did it! Thanks a lot. I feel like an idiot now. I guess I just thought that since I added the list to the master list before I cleared it the data would be preserved in the master list, but I guess not.

Comment: Don't feel stupid, @slister; that's a thing to get used to with object references.  When you assign them to something else, your existing variable still refers to the same actual object on the heap. The `New` is what gives you a new object. :) Also, kudos for including exactly the right code to figure that out!

Comment: Thanks. This is why I love stack overflow. I knew if I just posted that code somebody would be able to figure out what was going on. I appreciate the explanation too because now I won't make that same mistake again.